# JSON to Oracle database table

Tags: json, oracle, csv

I have a requirement to write a JSON file to Oracle database table.

I tried converting the JSON file to CSV file with column wise but could not achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve in here.

1) Do you want to create a new table in Oracle， then populate the new table with data from JSON.

2) Or you just want to import data from JSON into databse?

For option one, I think need to write customized script or program to do so that.

For option two, some Oracle DBMS tools have import feature to perform this task.

Comment: Thanks Jeff i want to create a new table in Oracle and Import the data from JSON.